# Lua obfuscator, how to

Tags: lua

I understand this question will appear silly but I'm clueless what to do, which makes it even more silly. I have written a lua script for a game - which works, but I've never actually run any lua with the lua programs(from the site download). I would like to obfuscate my lua code with this tool: https://github.com/mlnlover11/XFuscator but I'm unsure how to do it, I tried running the lua program and browsing there, dropping the xfuscator file on top of the program etc but nothing has given any result.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command line (e.g. under windows, that's `cmd`). Go into the directory where you have your local copy of XFuscator. Make sure lua is on your PATH. Type

```
lua XFuscator.lua -h
```

This should show the help message, which will describe the next steps.

Comment: thank you for the reply, what do you mean with PATH? I used pushd to navigate to desktop/xfuscator-master/

Comment: PATH is an environment variable that tells the command line where to look for executable files. You may just run the command and if it tells you "lua: [something] not found", you need to look where you have lua on your system.

Comment: I have E:\lua\bin, include, lib, share and in the \bin there is lua.exe, luac.exe, luadist.exe and some other ones, how do I make environment variable there?

Comment: Then ignore PATH and just call `E:\lua\bin\lua XFuscator.lua -h` from the XFuscator directory.